# properties of adjoint operators and anti-hermitian operators

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators

If $A$ is an operator on $H$. Show that :

(a) $A$ is anti-Hermitian if and only if $iA$ is self-adjoint.

(b) $A-A^{*}$ is anti-Hermitian.

---

I'm search what means a anti-Hermitian operator and I found that if $S$ is anti-Hermitian for the inner product is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle Sw,z\rangle = -\langle w,Sz\rangle
\end{eqnarray*}
For $w,z \in H$.

$A^{*}$ is the adjoint operator of $A$.

---

So My work for (b) is:

Let $w,s\in H$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle (A-A^{*})w,z\rangle&=&\langle w,(A-A^{*})^{*}z \rangle \\
&=& \langle w,(A^{*}-A)z\rangle\\
&=&- \langle w,(A-A^{*})z \rangle
\end{eqnarray*}
So, $A-A^{*}$ is a anti-Hermitian operator. Is this correct?. But I'm confuse with (a) if I take this definition of anti-Hermitian operator.

Comment: If $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, then $(\lambda A)^\ast=\bar\lambda A^\ast$ (can you show this?). What follows for $\lambda=i$?

Comment: If $A=A^*$, then $(iA)^*=(-i)A^*=-iA$ means $iA$ is anti-Hermitian. And, if $iA$ is anti-Hermitian, then $A=A^*$ is Hermitian.